# Starting Windows cmd scripts with java ProcessBuilder: Difference in Java Versions?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am starting a cmd script on Windows 7 (in my case mvn.cmd from Maven) by using a ProcessBuilder:

```
 Process p = ProcessBuilder("mvn.cmd", "-help").start();
```

Starting this with Java 6 seems to do nothing (no effect and no output on the Stream), while using Java 7, the script is started exactly as if used in the command line.

Can somebody explain to me what change in Java might cause this behaviour?

Comment: By "exactly as on the command line", do you mean that you run your Java main() from a terminal?

Comment: No. I mean that the process behaves as if I just enter "mvn.cmd -help" into a cmd prompt.

Comment: A process has both a standard _output_ and a standard _error_; what happens with Java 6 if you `.redirectErrorStream(true)` with Java 6 (this basically redirects stderr to stdout)?